# laravel redirects to login again after authentication

Tags: laravel, redirect

After authentication admin login page redirecting back to login again, tried many solutions

here is logincontroller

```
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you register your middleware in Kernal.php
if yes then how are you applying your middleware whether is it on web.php or controller ?
the easiest way to check is to

```
dd(Auth::guard($guard));
 if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    return redirect('/home');
}

return $next($request);
```

you will see a black screen which means you have applied the middleware but if you don't see then you have to register and apply middleware.